How can I correctly return an AWS SdkStream in Node.js + Fastify?
After retrieving a file from an S3 bucket using the getObjectCommand from my NodeJs with Fastify backend, I am trying to return the Body of type SdkStream in the response. However, the response does not work as expected and I receive the following error:
"response will send, but you shouldn't use res.writeHead in stream mode. stream closed prematurely"

Below is the code of the API that I am using to get the file from the bucket and return it as a response:
    server.get(
    `${basePath}/download/:file_uuid`,
    {
        preHandler: (request, reply, done) =>  BasicAuthMiddleware(server, request, reply, done)
    },
    async (request, reply) => {

        try {

            const fileUUID = request.params.file_uuid;
            const bucket = process.env.aws_bucket_name;
            const accessKeyId = process.env.accessKeyId;
            const secretAccessKey = process.env.secretAccessKey;

            if(!accessKeyId) 
                throw new MissingParameter('AWS accessKeyId is missing', 500)

            if(!secretAccessKey) 
                throw new MissingParameter("AWS secretAccessKey is missing", 500);    

            if(!bucket) 
                throw new MissingParameter("Bucket name is missing from configs", 500)

            if(!fileUUID) {
                throw new MissingParameter("File UUID is missing", 500)
            }

            const s3Configs: S3ClientConfig = {
                region: process.env.aws_region,
                credentials: {
                    accessKeyId: process.env.accessKeyId!,
                    secretAccessKey: process.env.secretAccessKey!
                }
            }

            // * get the file infos (filename, mimetype...) from db
            const storedFileInfos = await server.pool_db.query(`
                SELECT * 
                FROM ${schema}.files 
                WHERE s3_filename = $1`, [ fileUUID ]);

            if(!storedFileInfos?.rows?.length) 
                throw new Error("File not found in saved uploads")
        
            const storedFile = storedFileInfos?.rows[0];

            const { filename, mimetype } = storedFile;

            // * get the file from s3 and serve it 
            const s3Client = new S3Client(s3Configs) as NodeJsClient<S3Client>;
            const command = new GetObjectCommand({ Bucket: bucket, Key: fileUUID })
            const { Body } = await s3Client.send(command);

            return reply.header(`Content-disposition`, `attachment; filename=${filename}`).type(mimetype).send(Body);
        } catch(error: any) {
            console.error(error);

            return reply.code(error.status ?? 500).send({
                statusCode: error.status ?? 500,
                message: error.message
            })
        }
    }
)


The Body.transformToWebStream() should work

How would the implementation look like with Body.transformToWebStream()?

reply.send(Body.transformToWebStream())

@ManuelSpigolon I found out that the problem of the stream closing prematurely was caused by the preHandler middleware. I ended up using my solution, which is now working fine with the corrected preHandler.
